# SQL- How to select all dynamic parent and child data in 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all data that have parent and child. I have a sample table like this:

```
ID  Name        Parent  
1   Mike        6000    
2   Mike_x1     1
3   Mike_x2     2
4   Mike_x3     6333
5   Mike_x4     2
6   Mike_x5     3
7   Bob_x2      5
```

first of all i select data to get a header:

```
select * from table1 where parent = 1
```

and i get header data like this:

```
ID  Name        Parent
2   Mike_x1     1
```

from the header i got a new ID = 2 as a header data. So i select again to get a child:

```
select * from table1 where parent = 2
```

and i get data like this:

```
ID  Name        Parent
3   Mike_x2     2
5   Mike_x4     2
```

from the first child i got a new ID = 3 and ID = 5. So i select again to get another child:

```
select * from table1 where parrent = 3
```

and

```
select * from table1 where parrent = 5
```

and i got data like this:

```
ID  Name        Parrent
6   Mike_x5     3
```

and

```
ID  Name        Parrent
7   Bob_x2      5
```

Thats my steps to get parent and child. But i want to select using 1 query to get all parent and child data. When i do first select to get header `select * from table1 where parrent = 1` , i will get a result like this:

```
ID  Name        Parrent
2   Mike_x1     1
3   Mike_x2     2
5   Mike_x4     2
6   Mike_x5     3
7   Bob_x2      5
```

Anybody help me? Is it possible for me to do it by 1 query, which is don't need to select manual like select * from where parent = 1,2,3,5 etc

Comment: Hierarchical queries in SQL server use `For XML path` syntax or [Common table expressions CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) [Example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: To do this in basic SQL syntax, you'd have to do a it of re-indexing. This book, [Trees and Hierarchies in SQL](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334) has brilliant advice on how to accomplish it.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the answer, Ok i'll try it. I'm sorry because i don't have any idea to this case. Do you think that i need to create stored procedure? Or is it enough to use For XML Path? Because i'm avoid to use Stored Procedure

Comment: @frances Thanks to give me some reference, because i don't have an idea for this case. Really big thanks

Comment: @bagusofterror, I'm not sure it's needed in this example since you're not really traversing the hierarchy.  you only care about 1 level up and 1 level down.  So two joins should be able to accomplish it.  The references were for assistance with more complex data.

Comment: @xQbert I thought the question was about getting all recursive children and parent data, based on the description of iteratively descending the tree to find distant child records.

Comment: @bagsusofterror what is the expected result.  I think you want IDs, 2,3,5 as the they are the records that have both parents and children.  If so, then my answer should be correct.

Comment: @frances I have a different understanding of the question. based on the first statement `I want to select all data that have parent and child`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Parent FROM table1)
AND Parent IN (SELECT ID FROM table1)
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my understanding of the question is correct, this will " select all data that have parent and child"

```
Select T1.*
FROM TableName T1
INNER JOIN tableName Parents
 on T1.ParentID = Parents.ID
INNER JOIN tableName Kids
 on Kids.ParentID = T1.ID
```

corrected inner join on last element Kids.ID should have been Kids.ParentID

Should result in

```
    ID  Name        Parent  
    2   Mike_x1     1 
    3   Mike_x2     2 
    5   Mike_x4     2
```

This works because of the inner self joins which exclude records that don't have parents or kids.

If these aren't the desired results: what are the expected results?

If you need to know who the parents are and who the kids are simply add to the select

```
Select t1.*, Parents.*, Kids.*
```

However if you need to traverse the hieracy and list the parents kids of kids etc... then XML path or a cte is needed.